# Getting Cassandra query results asynchronously using Scala + Monix

Tags: scala, cassandra, observable, reactive-programming, monix

I'm building a REST API using [AKKA Http](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/), [Monix](https://monix.io/) and [Datastax Java Driver for Apache Cassandra](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) and I'm having some troubles while trying to fetch some Items from cassandra, wait for the query to be fulfilled and returning the results.

> I'm able to print all the results easily, but unable to wait for the
>   query to be done and return all the items. My rest point simply
>   returns an empty array of items since it does not wait for the query
>   to be done.

I have an `executeQuery` method that takes:

- `queryString: String` representing a cassandra query
- `page: Int` useful for pagination
- `parameters: Any*` representing parameters, if necessary for the query

And returns an `Observable[Row]`.

Then, in order to perform such query, retrieve its result, parse them and send them back, I use [Monix Observable and Subscription](https://monix.io/docs/2x/reactive/observable.html).

Let's suppose I want to retrieve some items by a common field known as `pid`:

```
import monix.execution.Ack
import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global
import com.datastax.driver.core.Row
import monix.reactive.Observable

import cassandra.src.CassandraHelper
import item.src.entity.{Item, Items}

. . .
val keyspace = "my_keyspace"
val table = "items"
. . .

def getItems() : Items = {
  var itemList: Items = List()
  val observable: Observable[Row] = CassandraHelper.executeQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM " + keyspace + "." + table,
    1
  )
  observable.subscribe { row =>
    itemList ::= ItemMapper.rowToItem()(row)
    Ack.Continue
  }
  Items(itemList)
}
```

Where `rowToItem` simply parses a row into an `Item` and `Items: List[Item]`.
I was taking a look at [Task](https://monix.io/docs/2x/eval/task.html) but I'm not quite sure its what I'm looking for.

**EDIT**

With @Alexandru Nedelcu solution I'm able to print all the `items` in `itemList` as soon as they get inserted into it, but still getting an empty response for that call: `{ "items" : [] }`.

Here's the edited code:

```
def getItems() : Items = {
  var itemList: List[Item] = List()
  val observable: Observable[Row] = CassandraHelper.executeQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM " + keyspace + "." + table,
    1
  )
  observable.subscribe { row =>
    println(itemList)
    itemList ::= ItemMapper.rowToItem()(row)
    Ack.Continue
  }
  Items(itemList)
}
```

**How can I wait for the results to be all parsed and inserted into items and then send them back?**

Comment: Hey, that's not what I told you to do :-) The problem is that you're returning a synchronous `Items(itemList)` without waiting on the `observable` to complete. Look at my code below and notice that you won't see a `subscribe` and that the returned result is a `Task` (which is a lazy `Future`), being "completed" by "foldLeftL", which will emit a result after the source observable completes. No blocking and no manual "subscribe" or manual "runAsync".

Comment: Hi @AlexandruNedelcu I'll try that asap and I'll let you know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you have an `Observable[Row]` and you want to build an `Items` out of it, which aggregates every `Row` element from the source stream, is that correct?

If so, the `foldLeftL` is what you want, which will aggregate every element into a state and return the final result once the source stream completes:

```scala
// We need to suspend the Task, because your Items is probably a
// mutable object and it's best to suspend side effects ;-)
val items: Task[Items] = Task.suspend {
  val initial: Items = _
  val observable: Observable[Row] = ???

  // This returns a Task[Items] when the source completes
  observable.foldLeftL(initial) { (items, elem) =>
    items ::= ItemMapper.rowToItem()(row)
    // I don't understand if your `Items` is mutable or not
    // but returning the same reference is fine
    items
  }
}
```

A `Task` is a lazy `Future`. And you can convert it into a `Future` with `runAsync`. More details here: https://monix.io/docs/2x/eval/task.html

Comment: Still unable to return the result. Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/AndreaM16/45aaf13e04ca6c3e34be73689340b56a) with the code I set up.

Comment: @AndreaM16 in general I avoid blocking threads. Please test that code without an Await.result.

Comment: Edited my question @Alexandru Nedelcu

Comment: @AndreaM16 see my reply above.